# Changing the web.config takes the WCF service down?

Tags: wcf, iis, web-config, automapper

I have a simple WCF service hosted on IIS. Anytime I change the web.config file the service goes down and shows the following error:

> Could not load file or assembly
>   'AutoMapper, Version=1.1.0.188,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005' or
>   one of its dependencies. Logon
>   failure: unknown user name or bad
>   password. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007052E)

To correct it, I need to delete all existing files and re-publish the WCF service. Re-publishing without deleting old files doesn't work, and neither does restarting the iis server.

Does anyone know why this happens? Or if there is an alternative to republishing the service to bring it back up? I am using IIS on Windows Server 2003, which I think is 6.0, and .Net framework 4.0

Further Error Info...

> Assembly Load Trace: The following
>   information can be helpful to
>   determine why the assembly
>   'AutoMapper, Version=1.1.0.188,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005' could
>   not be loaded.
>
> WRN: Assembly binding logging is
>   turned OFF. To enable assembly bind
>   failure logging, set the registry
>   value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog]
>   (DWORD) to 1. Note: There is some
>   performance penalty associated with
>   assembly bind failure logging. To turn
>   this feature off, remove the registry
>   value
>   [HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
>
> Stack Trace:
>
> [FileLoadException: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'AutoMapper,
>   Version=1.1.0.188, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005' or
>   one of its dependencies. Logon
>   failure: unknown user name or bad
>   password. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007052E)]
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly._nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +0
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.nLoad(AssemblyName
>   fileName, String codeBase, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, RuntimeAssembly
>   locationHint, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean
>   throwOnFileNotFound, Boolean
>   forIntrospection, Boolean
>   suppressSecurityChecks) +39
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoadAssemblyName(AssemblyName
>   assemblyRef, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection,
>   Boolean suppressSecurityChecks) +132
>   System.Reflection.RuntimeAssembly.InternalLoad(String
>   assemblyString, Evidence
>   assemblySecurity, StackCrawlMark&
>   stackMark, Boolean forIntrospection)
>   +144    System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(String
>   assemblyString) +28
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.ServiceHostFactory.CreateServiceHost(String
>   constructorString, Uri[]
>   baseAddresses) +208
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.CreateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +1440
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.ActivateService(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +44
>   System.ServiceModel.HostingManager.EnsureServiceAvailable(String
>   normalizedVirtualPath) +615
>
> [ServiceActivationException: The
>   service
>   '/Services/ClientLoginService.svc'
>   cannot be activated due to an
>   exception during compilation.  The
>   exception message is: Could not load
>   file or assembly 'AutoMapper,
>   Version=1.1.0.188, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=be96cd2c38ef1005' or
>   one of its dependencies. Logon
>   failure: unknown user name or bad
>   password. (Exception from HRESULT:
>   0x8007052E).]
>   System.Runtime.AsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +679246
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.End(IAsyncResult
>   result) +190
>   System.ServiceModel.Activation.HostedHttpRequestAsyncResult.ExecuteSynchronous(HttpApplication
>   context, String
>   routeServiceVirtualPath, Boolean
>   flowContext, Boolean ensureWFService)
>   +234    System.ServiceModel.Activation.HttpModule.ProcessRequest(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) +355
>   System.Web.SyncEventExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   +148    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep
>   step, Boolean& completedSynchronously)
>   +75

Comment: Is the AutoMapper assembly in the bin directory or in the GAC?

Comment: Just as a short answer to your title question: Yes, modifiying your Web.config will trigger a restart of the website your WCF service is hosted in.

Comment: @Richard Its just in the bin directory

Comment: @Filburt I don't mind it restarting the service, but I do mind it not bring it back up correctly

Comment: You're getting a logon failure.  How is this authentication being performed?  Windows authentication?  Some other method?  Seems that the file isn't being loaded because the identity doesn't have access to the file.

Comment: @David The site uses Windows Autentication

Comment: Does Automapper support .Net 4?  I looked at the source in GitHub and it appears to have hard dependencies on .Net 3.5 because of Castle Core.

Comment: @Jeff I think so.... it compiles and runs just fine. I don't see why it wouldn't.

Comment: Same for me (C# 3.5). I'm not using AutoMapper and I don't think it's related. Any time I change something in web.config, I have to restart the app or I get similar error when accessing WCF services.